# jQuery - Hiding elements not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new at jQuery (just picked up a book this morning!) and I'm trying to hide an element; it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if ($) {
                $(document).ready(

                    function() {

                        $('ul li span').click(

                            function() {
                                $(this).parent().children('ul').hide();
                            }

                        );

                    }

                );
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

            <ul>                        
                <li><a href="">My Controls <span class="arrow">&uarr;</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">My Profile</a></li>      
                    </ul>       
                </li>
            </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is the full code I'm using. When I click the span tag I want it to hide the inner `<ul>`. I assumed that `this` would access the `span` element, `parent()` the `li`, and `children()` the `ul` contained instead the `li`, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Am I making some sort of stupid mistake here?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten this by navigating directly to the parent (note: parents('selector') climbs the ancestors until a match, no more .parent().parent()... guessing):

```
$(this).parents('li').find('ul').hide();
```

Also, I suggest this for more effect:

```
$(this).parents('li').find('ul').slideUp();
```

Your ul elements aren't children of your span or your anchor, they're children of the li they both belong to.  Traversing up to this then hiding all ul beneath is what you're after I believe.

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the span you get the parent of the spam (the a) and look for its ul children — it doesn't have any.

You need to go up another level.

Comment: Using `$(this).parent().parent().children('ul').hide();` doesn't seem to work either, assuming that's how you do it. It does make the child `ul` flash, but not stay hidden.

Answer (score 1):

The following works, clicking the arrow (and only by clicking the arrow, though I suspect that's intentional on your part), hides the child `<ul>`, in FF3.0.12, Ubuntu 8.04. Though for some reason it seems unnecessarily complex.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($) {
        $(document).ready(

            function() {

                $('ul li span').click(

                    function() {

                            $(this).parent().parent().children('ul').hide(); // Original (modified) technique

// Nick's technique: $(this).parents('li').find('ul').hide();
// My preferred technique: $(this).parents('li').find('ul').toggle();
                        }

                );

            }

        );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

'this' represents DOM element. You need jQuery wrapper for it, $(this). Try

```
$(this).parent().children('ul').hide();
```

Comment: Sorry, that was an error when I copied across - fixed and it still doesn't work.